# textbox only allow ip address without validating untill ip is written c#

Tags: c#, textbox, ip

I'm trying to make a textbox only allow IP Addresses without validation using internet. I'm going to have a "private void textBox3_TextChanged" which does the job. and each time I type, it will check if it is a valid. That's why I want it to be fast, and only use a simple local code to check if it's valid, meaning 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255.

First, it should not do anything, but when an ip has been written, it will start a timer which then checks if the ip is reachable or not.
The goal of this, is that when the IP has been written, a picturebox will turn red if ip is not reachable after about 4 secounds, and if it's reachable, it will turn green, then stop till "textbox3_TextChanged"

I tried something like ping, but it crashed if nothing was typed:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

        options.DontFragment = false;


        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "ping";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(textBox3.Text, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        }
        else
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Without showing your efforts this seems just another _'gimme teh codez'_ kind of questions

Comment: What do you mean by "answer in different ways".

Comment: Here is one way: http://www.regextester.com/22

Comment: WebForms? WinForms? IPv4? IPv6?

Comment: I guess it's kind of 'gimme teh codez" but since I'v searched for a while now, and getting tired, I rather posted a question.

Comment: I edited the post more specific (sorry I was just too lazy). Please try and see if you can answer it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below mentioned code to validate IP ADD

```
public bool IsValidIp(string addr)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    bool valid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(addr) && IPAddress.TryParse(addr, out ip);
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I edited the post because of bad explanation, and this didn't answer my question